# Using wild type characters on paths for Charles breakpoints

Tags: charles-proxy

Im trying to accomplish a capture all breakpoint for a path that changes each time it's called. For instance once its called `accounts/validate_device/trans/_accounts_validate_device_d7be5ea4-2b3c-4c20-8190-2c7653af83jj` nd then next time everything after `accounts/validate_device/trans/` changes. Whats the wild type character, or is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Ah so simple it was `*` not sure why it didn't work the first time